# Formatting with UNIX

Tags: shell, unix, sed, string-formatting

I have asked a similar question and sorry to ask this but I am not getting how to fix it.

Input:

```
+1234.56,a,b,,++,+++++++,+++,+546.76,a,b
```

Desired Output:

```
1234.56,a,b,,++,+++++++,+++,546.76,a,b
```

I want the '+' to be removed only from the decimal numbers. So basically my requirement is to convert signed numbers into unsigned.

Please help and thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you also want `-1234.56` to become `1234.56`? What have you tried?

Comment: No as of now that is not my requirement and only changing +1234.56 to 1234.56 would suffice, but it would be great to cover the scenario which you mentioned. I tried the simple sed (as I am a beginner) but its replacing + from ++,+++++++,+++ as well which I want to keep intact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't like the solution completely... but it works although it adds a trailing comma at the end:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=","} {for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {if ($i+0==$i) {$i=$i+0}; printf "%s,", $i}}' a
1234.56,a,b,,++,+++++++,+++,546.76,a,b,
```

#### Explanation

The idea is to perform a `$field + 0`, so that if it is numeric the `+` will fall. Otherwise, the string will keep the same. So the solution loops through all fields (based on comma delimiter, `FS`) and prints them after doing that check.

---

To get rid of the trailing comma, Saurabh suggests this way:

```
awk ... | sed 's/.$//g'
```

Comment: Just adding to your solution and it works. Please find below the final command that worked for me: awk 'BEGIN{FS=","} {for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {if ($i+0==$i) {$i=$i+0}; printf "%s,", $i}}' | sed 's/.$//g'

Comment: Ah, great, so you delete the trailing comma with `sed`. Good one.

Answer (score 1):

Using `gnu awk`, you can do this:

```
awk '{print gensub(/\+([0-9])/,"\\1","g")}' file
1234.56,a,b,,++,+++++++,+++,546.76,a,b
```

It removes the `+` when its in front of any number `[0-9]`

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
 sed -r 's/(^|,)\+([0-9]+\.[0-9]+)/\1\2/g' file
```

or (at a pinch):

```
 sed -r 's/(^|,)\+([0-9])/\1\2/g' file
```

Capture the start of file or a comma in backreference 1, followed by `+` sign, followed by capturing a number followed by a `.` followed by a number into back reference 2. Replace by backreference 1 and 2.